# Bug in sort or misunderstanding

Tags: unix, sorting

Suppose I have this file

```
b 10 foo
a 10 bar
a 2 bar
```

I want to sort by the third colum, alphabetically. In case of ties, I want to sort by the second column, numerically. In the man page for the unix sort program you find this:

```
> sort -k3 -k2n a
```

Which gives

```
a 2 bar
a 10 bar
b 10 foo
```

Which is correct.

Now, what I actually want, is to sort by the first column, alphabetically, and in case of ties, by the second column, numerically. Can anybody explain to me why

```
> sort -k1 -k2n a
```

Gives

```
a 10 bar
a 2 bar
b 10 foo
```

Which is plain wrong?

Comment: try -k1,1 -k2,2n but this is really more a superuser question since no programming is involed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your example doesn't work as you expect is that `sort` considers all positions *after* the specified one as well. In your example, the dictionary sort of `-k1` sorts the string `a 10 bar` before `a 2 bar`, and you don't need a tie break.

You need to explicitly specify the limits of the sort key, as described in the man page:

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
```

Example:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2n theFile
a 2 bar
a 10 bar
b 10 foo
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I would only need POS2 if I would want to sort using a range of columns and missed the default behaviour of sort using the remainder of the line from POS1 for sorting! Now it works like a charm.